# Wpf InvalidCastException: unable to cast list to single object

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a wpf project with a database, and I use Dapper to use this data.
After this query:

```
public Gebruiker GetGebruiker(int id)
        {
            // Stap 2 Dapper
            // Uitschrijven SQL statement & bewaren in een string. 
            string sql = "Select * from Gebruiker where ID = " + id;

            // Stap 3 Dapper
            // Uitvoeren SQL statement op db instance 
            return (Gebruiker)db.Query<Gebruiker>(sql);

        }
```

I get following error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[project_amber_akkermans.Model.Gebruiker]' to type 'project_amber_akkermans.Model.Gebruiker'.'

I'm not sure what goes wrong here, or how I can make the query return one object, not an array with one object in, as now happens I think. I don't know if you need any more information, but I'm happy to provide, all help is welcome!

Comment: looks like query returns a list. use `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: And where do I place that?

Comment: after calling `.Query`.

Comment: Found it, thank you!

Comment: Code in het nederlands? wie doet dat nou :0

Comment: A better approach for retrieving single row is the QuerySingle method of dapper, here is the link: https://dapper-tutorial.net/querysingle

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you:

```
public Gebruiker GetGebruiker(int id)
{
    // Stap 2 Dapper
    // Uitschrijven SQL statement & bewaren in een string. 
    string sql = $"Select * from Gebruiker where ID = {id};";

    // Stap 3 Dapper
    // Uitvoeren SQL statement op db instance 
    return db.QueryFirstOrDefault<Gebruiker>(sql);
}
```